# LM35 max input current - I have a wrong output from the sensor

Tags: sensor, circuit-design, temperature, lm35

I’m currently doing a small project. I’m trying to make my first pcb.

That’s for a light I made.

But the LM35DZ outputs a wrong voltage.

My LM35 puts out 4.6V instead of 380mV.

With a 12V - 2A power supply.

With the datasheet I can’t find the maximum input current.

Do you have an idea?

This is my circuit:

[image]

Datasheet : https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/LM35DZ-NOPB?qs=QbsRYf82W3F5RpWTxhXHxA%3D%3D

The component is wired to the CN1 jst

R6 : 47 ohm
R5 : 330 ohm

With a 3,3V linear regulator.

Comment: Please add a link to the datasheet into your question using the edit link below the question. Note that you can make your schematic *much* more easy to read by using GND symbols close to each component attached to ground instead of wiring. Also note that there is no LM35 in your schematic. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: The LM35 is probably intended to be connected to CN1.

Comment: Are you sure about the values for the voltage divider R5 and R6?  That's probably not the cause of the problem with the LM35, but certainly looks odd.

Comment: There is the datasheet for th lm35DZ/nopb :https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/LM35DZ-NOPB?qs=QbsRYf82W3F5RpWTxhXHxA%3D%3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LM35 was damaged. miss wiring. Because of that the LM35 ouput a wrong voltage when it was correctly wired. Thank you for yours helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Mouser link clearly indicates

> Output Current:
>   10 mA  max

However, it will not pull down negative bias current since the sensor uses an NPN emitter follower output inside a feedback loop with low quiescent current.

Therefore put a resistor on the signal input of the floating LM324 (PNP inputs) to ground e.g. 1k to 10k.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your circuit up to the LM324 input. Check that the LM324 GND pin is actually connected to ground, and check the wiring to the LM35. Check it with a meter.

If the LM324 GND is open, the several mA current will exceed the ~1uA sink capability of the LM35.

Failing that, perhaps you have a mis-wired or damaged LM35, but you have not provided a schematic for that part of the circuit.